# Typical Execute Usage in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing some stored procedures and im using some of the other written procedures as a starting template (created by someone else) and i notice that 'EXECUTE' statements have been used for very simple queries and im just wandering if there is an advantage to this or whether its just his style.

So this below is similar to what I keep finding but its not how I would attempt it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspDeleteItem] (@ItemID varchar(max)) 
AS

BEGIN

  -- checks for existing Data associated with the Item
  if fnItemChildCount(@ItemID) > 0
    begin
      return 1
    end

  execute ('delete tblItems where ID = ' + @ItemID)

END
```

Next is how i would think about doing it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspDeleteItem] (@ItemID varchar(max)) 
AS

BEGIN

  -- checks for existing Data associated with the Item
  if fnItemChildCount(@ItemID) > 0
    begin
      return 1
    end

  DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblItems]
    WHERE [ID] = @ItemID

END
```

I am not an expert here but the guy writing the other SP's is (apparently) so I am just wandering if there is some advantage to the way he has done it over what I would do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's generally no advantage and it leaves you open to SQL injection as well as bloating the plan cache with single use plans. It also prevents ownership chaining meaning that you have to grant `delete` permissions on the underlying object as well as `exec` on the procedure.

The one case where this might have a slight benefit is if the query is vulnerable to parameter sniffing but in that case you can leave the query parameterised and add `option (recompile)` to have it compiled taking into account the actual parameter value. This is not going to be an issue with singleton seeks on an ID column anyway.

The datatype of `@itemid` still looks suspect in your improved version. The parameter should have the same datatype as the column.

Comment: OK thanks, ill just stick with my method. Yes ideally i would use an INT but im also writing the program used with this SP  (and many others) which is passing strings so to avoid confusion there im keeping it that way but pre-checking everything within the program.